# Material Button background gradient

Tags: android, android-button, material-components

Is there a way i could set a gradient color to a MaterialButton from the google material library. 
app:backgroundTint only sets color but not gradient color

Answer (score 5):

`MaterialButton` ignored `android:background` until release [`1.2.0-alpha06`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/309d71860f0686137277915fb09e7502cbafc2b4).

With this release you can use something like:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button_gradient"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    ... />
```

If you require this functionality with earlier versions of the library you can use the `AppCompatButton`. Something like:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button_gradient"
```

Answer (score 3):

not sure about this but according to [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton)
we can't even add `android:background`, it seems that adding `drawable` to `materialButton` is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it by using default method. Better use **gradient drawable**.

Create a new xml file and put it in drawable and then add it to button as background

**gradient.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
   <gradient
      android:startColor="#000000"
      android:centerColor="#ffffff"
      android:endColor="#cfcfcf"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

**layout.xml**

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:text="YourText" >
```

Comment: I know how to do that. What I’m wondering is can it be done on MaterialButton from material components library by google

Comment: No default method for doing this.

Answer (score -2):

Create drawable file, for examle

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="135"
    android:centerColor="#6200ee"
    android:endColor="#6200ee"
    android:startColor="#3700b3"
    android:type="linear" />
 </shape>
```

and set as background of button this file

Comment: Is it possible to do it on MaterialButton